# Only weight paint on visible vertices

Tags: vertex-groups, brushes, weight-paint-mode

How do I only paint on visible vertices?

[image: weight paint scenarios]
<sup>The brush used in the image a full weight, full strength projected add brush with constant fall-off.</sup>

In image A I only want to paint on the visible vertex. However, the occluded vertex is painted as well.

In image B I want to paint on all the visible vertices. However, the visible vertex in back is not painted on, although it is enclosed in the brush circle.

Both scenarios don't work as expected. How can I weight paint, so that the visible vertices under the brush get painted on?

PS: The circle select in edit mode works exactly how I would expect a paintbrush to behave. It paint on all visible vertices in the circle brush area.
[image: edit mode]

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for you:

- Go to edit mode and enable: Viewport Overlays / Shading -> Vertex Group Weights:

[image]

- Create a Vertex Group and select the desired weight.
- Press "C" to circle select and select the vertices.
- Press "Enter" (or right click) and then "Assign" button in the Vertex group:

*Tip: you can add "Assign" as Quick Favorites, so when you press "q" is handy.

[image]

- Click on an empty space to deselect all vertices and then repeat the process.